# Directing sound output for specific applications

Tags: linux, audio, kubuntu

I'm trying to direct the sound from Youtube running in Opera to my sound card's HDMI output (to a TV), but still have all other OS sounds go to my PC's "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" playback device.

I'm able to get everything to go to one device or the other, but can't find a way to split the sound like I need. I suppose because Opera/Flash (and probably most everything else I'm using, like Wine games) are just not "Phonon aware", so they end up in the Default/Unspecified Category).

[image: Phonon]

Is there some way to force a specific application into one of the other "audio playback categories" (see below)?  Any other non-distro specific Linux solutions?

I'm using Kubuntu (14.04), and it appears I have something called "Phonon multimedia framework" installed here in charge of all this.

Comment: Well, that didn't work out, did it?